# Is it possible to setup a Windows 2008 R2 KMS server for windows 7 Licensing only?

Tags: windows-7, licensing, kms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

The question is in the Title, I had the impression that you needed a Windows 2008 R2 KMS key to setup the KMS host, even if you wanted to activate Windows 7 licenses only.
Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I wrong ?

yes and no. You need a 2008 R2 KMS key to activate KMS, but what KMS can activate depends on the class of the key.

http://www.itechtalk.com/thread439.html

There is a KMS key that allows KMS to ONLY activate Windows 7 and no other WIndows Servers.

Answer (score 1):

The KMs service activates anybody that asks for activation from vista on up.  In order for your server to activate computers, you must have at least 5 Servers checked in for server activation to occur or 25 Windows 7 or Vista machines checked in for client activation to occur.